# How can I convert list of dictionaries to list of lists?

Tags: python

I have data like

```
data = [{'name':'a', 'description':'1'}, {'name':'b', 'description':'2'}]
```

I want to convert the above to list of lists like this:

```
data = [['a', '1'], ['b', '2']]
```

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter("name", "description")
print([getter(item) for item in data])
# [('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]
```

If you wanted list of lists, then you can do

```
print([list(getter(item)) for item in data])
# [['a', '1'], ['b', '2']]
```

Comment: Why not simply `[elem.values() for elem in data]`?

Comment: @Abhijit The order will not be predictable

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [[entry['name'], entry['description']] for entry in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{'name':'a', 'description':'1'}, {'name':'b', 'description':'2'}]

c = []

for d in data:

    c.append(d.values())

print c

Output: [['a', '1'], ['b', '2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

list of dictionaries to list of lists:

```
    lstoflst=[list(lstofdct[0].keys()) ] + [ list(x.values()) for x in lstofdct] )
```

list of list to list of dictionaries:

```
    lstofdct=[ dict(zip(lstoflst[0],x)) for x in lstoflst[1:len(lstoflst)] ]
```